# call method on running process from parent process

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write a program that interfaces with hardware via pyserial according to this diagram https://github.com/kiyoshi7/Intrument/blob/master/Idea.gif . my problem is that I don't know how to tell the child process to run a method.

I tried reducing my problem down to the essence of what I am trying to do can call the method request() from the main script. I just dont know how to handle two way communication like this, in examples using queue i just see data shared or i cant understand the examples

```
import multiprocessing 
from time import sleep

class spawn:
    def __init__(self, _number, _max):
        self._number = _number
        self._max = _max
        self.Update()

    def request(self, x):
        print("{} was requested.".format(x))

    def Update(self):
        while True:
            print("Spawned {} of {}".format(self._number, self._max))
            sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=spawn, args=(1,1))
    p.start()
    sleep(5)
    p.request(2) #here I'm trying to run the method I want
```

update thanks to Carcigenicate

```
import multiprocessing 
from time import sleep
from operator import methodcaller

class Spawn:
    def __init__(self, _number, _max):
        self._number = _number
        self._max = _max
        # Don't call update here

    def request(self, x):
        print("{} was requested.".format(x))

    def update(self):
        while True:
            print("Spawned {} of {}".format(self._number, self._max))
            sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spawn = Spawn(1, 1)  # Create the object as normal

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=methodcaller("update"), args=(spawn,)) # Run the loop in the process
    p.start()

    while True:
        sleep(1.5)
        spawn.request(2)  # Now you can reference the "spawn"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to rearrange things a bit. I would not do the long running (infinite) work from the constructor. That's generally poor practice, and is complicating things here. I would instead initialize the object, *then* run the loop in the separate process:

```
from operator import methodcaller

class Spawn:
    def __init__(self, _number, _max):
        self._number = _number
        self._max = _max
        # Don't call update here

    def request(self, x):
        print("{} was requested.".format(x))

    def update(self):
        while True:
            print("Spawned {} of {}".format(self._number, self._max))
            sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spawn = Spawn(1, 1)  # Create the object as normal

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=methodcaller("update"), args=(spawn,)) # Run the loop in the process
    p.start()

    spawn.request(2)  # Now you can reference the "spawn" object to do whatever you like
```

Unfortunately, since `Process` requires that it's `target` argument is pickleable, you can't just use a `lambda` wrapper like I originally had (whoops). I'm using [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) to create a pickleable wrapper. `methodcaller("update")` returns a function that calls `update` on whatever is given to it, then we give it `spawn` to call it on.

You could also create a wrapper function using `def`:

```
def wrapper():
    spawn.update()

. . .

 p = multiprocessing.Process(target=wrapper)  # Run the loop in the process
```

But that only works if it's feasible to have `wrapper` as a global function. You may need to play around to find out what works best, or use a multiprocessing  library that doesn't require pickleable tasks.

---

Note, please use proper Python naming conventions. Class names start with capitals, and method names are lowercase. I fixed that up in the code I posted.

Comment: Whoops, realized that `target` needs to be pickleable. Sec.

Comment: how do I make it picklable? because I'm getting this error _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x031F6D20>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed

Comment: Thanks, but I just ran the code and for some reason request(x) isn't printing. I tried changing _number to something different what request is called but that also didnt do anything. on the plus side it seems that i dont have to use a terminal to see what is happening since IDLE now shows me what is being printed

Comment: I put a few print()s around that code and saw that everything stopped at p = multiprocessing... so despite multiprocessing it seems like everything is in only one process

Comment: @user169808 Oh, duh, I did something really stupid. Give `spawn` as an argument to the target similarly to how you had before with `(1, 1)`, instead of directly calling the function returned by `methodcaller`. The loop function is being called inside the argument list. The process is never even being created. I'll update my answer when I get on my desktop.

Comment: @user169808 Updated. Managed to get it fixed on my phone.

Comment: thanks it gave this error "TypeError: methodcaller needs at least one argument, the method name". I tried fixing it and it runs but i'm not sure how good of a solution it is, i'll add it to my post above.

Comment: @user169808 Did you remember to pass an "update" String like I showed?

Comment: its a bit odd when i run it on command prompt or double clicking the python file it shows me the error (putting a infinite loop in main to be able to see) and on idle it just prints what is in spawn.request() so it might be okay. But when I run it on windows PowerShell it works... It might be just a windows thing

Comment: @user169808 The code you posted doesn't even make use of methodcaller as far as I can see. That code can't be causing that error. It sounds like you're running two different scripts. Perhaps you didn't save the script after changing it, and IDLE works because it's using a cached version.

Comment: yes sorry i didn't notice i was mixing things up thanks for helping