# pyserial with multiprocessing gives me a ctype error

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle, pyserial

Hi I'm trying to write a module that lets me read and send data via `pyserial`. I have to be able to read the data in parallel to my main script. With the help of a stackoverflow user, I have a basic and working skeleton of [the program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443184/5999118), but when I tried adding a class I created that uses pyserial (handles finding port, speed, etc) found [here](https://github.com/kiyoshi7/PythonInterfaceInstrumentation/blob/master/SerialConnection.py) I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-830fa23bc600>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:.../pythonInterface1/Main.py', wdir='C:/Users/Daniel.000/Desktop/Daniel/Python/pythonInterface1')

  File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Daniel.000/Desktop/Daniel/Python/pythonInterface1/Main.py", line 39, in <module>
    p.start()

  File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)

  File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)

  File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)

  File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)

  File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)

ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
```

This is the code I am using to call the class in `SerialConnection.py`

```
import multiprocessing 
from time import sleep
from operator import methodcaller

from SerialConnection import SerialConnection as SC

class Spawn:
    def __init__(self, _number, _max):
        self._number = _number
        self._max = _max
        # Don't call update here

    def request(self, x):
        print("{} was requested.".format(x))

    def update(self):
        while True:
            print("Spawned {} of {}".format(self._number, self._max))
            sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    spawn = Spawn(1, 1)  # Create the object as normal
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=methodcaller("update"), args=(spawn,)) # Run the loop in the process
    p.start()
    while True:
        sleep(1.5)
        spawn.request(2)  # Now you can reference the "spawn"
    '''
    device = SC()
    print(device.Port)
    print(device.Baud)
    print(device.ID)
    print(device.Error)
    print(device.EMsg)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=methodcaller("ReadData"), args=(device,)) # Run the loop in the process
    p.start()
    while True:
        sleep(1.5)
        device.SendData('0003')
```

What am I doing wrong for this class to be giving me problems? Is there some form of restriction to use `pyserial` and multiprocessing together? I know it can be done but I don't understand how...

here is the traceback i get from python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:...\Python\pythonInterface1\Main.py", line 45, in <module>
    p.start()

  File "C:...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)

  File "C:...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)

  File "C:...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)

  File "C:...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)

  File "C:...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj) ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
```

Comment: You would be better off not running in a anaconda environment. Anaconda can break stuff at times.

Comment: ya i noticed, unfortunatly spyder is installed via anaconda, but I tried running it with idle and from the command line with a different python version but it didn't work as well

Comment: Can you paste that error traceback instead of the anaconda one? I would recommend switching the vs code or pycharm instead of spyder. Anaconda may kill you in the end.

Comment: I added the traceback I get from python 3.6

Comment: I mocked out `Device` but can't seem to get the error by doing that. Can you try to condense and/or rewrite your code so that the error still occurs but doesn't require any device connection?

Comment: Also a [possible resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179779/8150685)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to pass a `SerialConnection` instance to another process as an argument. For that python has first to serialize (pickle) the object, and it is not possible for `SerialConnection` objects.

As said in [Rob Streeting's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640312/pyserial-with-multiprocessing-gives-me-a-ctype-error#answer-57730270), a possible solution would be to allow the `SerialConnection` object to be copied to the other process' memory using the fork that occurs when `multiprocessing.Process.start` is invoked, but this will not work on Windows as it does not use fork.

A simpler, cross-platform and more efficient way to achieve parallelism in your code would be to use a thread instead of a process. The changes to your code are minimal:

```py
import threading
p = threading.Thread(target=methodcaller("ReadData"), args=(device,))
```

Comment: thanks I tested putting it in a thread and with a little more tweeting I managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is due to something inside `device` being **unpicklable** (i.e., not serializable by python). Take a look at [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) to see if you can see any rules that may be broken by something in your device object.

So why does `device` need to be picklable at all?

When a multiprocessing.Process is started, it uses fork() at the operating system level (unless otherwise specified) to create the new process. What this means is that the whole context of the parent process is "copied" over to the child. This **does not require pickling**, as it's done at the operating system level.

*(Note: On unix at least, this "copy" is actually a pretty cheap operation because it used a feature called "copy-on-write". This means that both parent and child processes actually read from the same memory until one or the other modifies it, at which point the original state is copied over to the child process.)*

However, the arguments of the function that you want the process to take care of **do** have to be pickled, because they are not part of the main process's context. So, that includes your `device` variable.

I think you might be able to resolve your issue by allowing `device` to be copied as part of the fork operation rather than passing it in as a variable. To do this though, you'll need a wrapper function around the operation you want your process to do, in this case `methodcaller("ReadData")`. Something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    device = SC()

    def call_read_data():
        device.ReadData()

    ...

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=call_read_data) # Run the loop in the process
    p.start()
```

Comment: thanks it was done this way for me to be able to call functions inside the new process. I want an instance of SerialCOnnection to be responsible for communicating with my hardware, but I dont want to lock the interpreter up while the instance is sending or receiving data. this is the main reason I am using process

Comment: The example I gave still uses a separate process to interact with the device, it just transfers the device to that process in a different way.

Comment: The OP is using ms-windows which *doesn't have* the `fork` system call. It uses a ms-windows specific system call that starts a new Python interpreter which *imports* the main module from the original process and then starts the worker function.